# Implement workflow to label Issue as "blocked" based on dependencies

Tags: github-actions, jq, github-cli, nektos-act

I am trying to implement a GitHub Actions workflow  that automatically labels an issue as "blocked" if it has dependencies on tasks that are still in progress. The action should be triggered when an issue is opened, edited, or reopened. Technical solution:

- Create a YAML file in the `.github/workflows` directory of the repository.
- The workflow should be triggered on issue events: opened, edited, and reopened.
- Use the GitHub CLI tool to fetch the state of dependent issues.
- Use jq to parse and filter JSON data.
- If a dependent issue is found to be open, label the current issue as "blocked".

So far I have

- Created file `label-blocked-issues.yml` in `.github/workflows`:

  ```yaml
  on:
    issues:
      types:
        - opened
        - edited
        - reopened

  jobs:
    label-blocked-issues:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - name: Checkout Repository
          uses: actions/checkout@v3

        - name: Install GitHub CLI
          run: |
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install gh

        - name: Authenticate with GitHub
          run: |
            echo -e "machine github.com\nlogin $GITHUB_ACTOR\npassword ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" > ~/.netrc
            chmod 600 ~/.netrc

        - name: Find and Label Blocked Issues
          id: find-blocked-issues
          run: |
            body=$(jq -r .issue.body $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH)
            dependencies=$(echo "$body" | grep -oE "#[0-9]+" | sed 's/#//g' || true)

            found_blocked=false
            for issue in $dependencies; do
              status=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
                -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
                "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/issues/$issue" | jq -r .state)

              if [ "$status" != "closed" ]; then
                echo "Issue #$issue is still open"
                found_blocked=true
              fi
            done

            if [[ "$found_blocked" == true ]]; then
              echo "::set-output name=blocked::true"
            fi

        - name: Label Issue as Blocked if
          if: steps.find-blocked-issues.outputs.blocked == 'true'
          run: |
            echo "Labeling issue as blocked..."
            echo "GitHub Repository: ${{ github.repository }}"
            echo "Issue Number: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}"

            # Use the GitHub token directly in the command
            gh api --method POST \
              -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
              -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
              -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
              /repos/${{ github.repository }}/issues/${{ github.event.issue.number }}/labels \
              -f "labels[]=blocked"
  ```
- Created file `test-event.json` within same directory:

  ```json
  {
    "action": "opened",
    "issue": {
      "number": 1,
      "title": "Test Issue",
      "body": "Depends on #123",
      "state": "open"
    }
  }
  ```
- Tested steps from file `label-blocked-issues.yml` together with `test-event.json` using Nektos/Act tool with Act Commands:

  `act -v -e .github/workflows/test-event.json -W . -j label-blocked-issues`

  or for simplicity:

  `act -e .github/workflows/test-event.json -W . -j label-blocked-issues`

  All steps runs and passed successfully, except of the last one *"Label Issue as Blocked if"*, when this step runs I get the following output:

  ```
  [label-blocked-issues.yml/label-blocked-issues] ⭐ Run Main Label Issue as Blocked if
  [label-blocked-issues.yml/label-blocked-issues]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/4] user= workdir=
  | Labeling issue as blocked...
  | GitHub Repository: treasure-house-of-projects/skarb-ngo
  | Issue Number: 1
  | Welcome to GitHub CLI!
  | 
  | To authenticate, please run `gh auth login`.
  [label-blocked-issues.yml/label-blocked-issues]   ❌  Failure - Main Label Issue as Blocked if
  [label-blocked-issues.yml/label-blocked-issues] exitcode '4': failure
  [label-blocked-issues.yml/label-blocked-issues]   Job failed
  Error: Job 'label-blocked-issues' failed
  ```

  So I am not able to pass GitHub CLI authentication.

I have tried different approaches related to `GITHUB_TOKEN`, `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN`, etc., also I try to include the authentication directly in the steps where it's needed:

```bash
gh auth login --with-token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

But nothing that I have done can pass the GitHub CLI authentication withing Nektos/Act test tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your problem is *only* with authenticating when running the workflow locally. Per [the `act` documentation](https://github.com/nektos/act#github_token):

> #### `GITHUB_TOKEN`
>
> GitHub [automatically provides](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#about-the-github_token-secret) a `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret when
> running workflows inside GitHub.
>
> If your workflow depends on this token, you need to create a [personal
> access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens) and pass it to `act` as a secret:
>
> ```
> act -s GITHUB_TOKEN=[insert token or leave blank and omit equals for secure input]
> ```
>
> If [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) is installed, the [`gh auth token`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_token) command can
> be used to automatically pass the token to act
>
> ```
> act -s GITHUB_TOKEN="$(gh auth token)"
> ```
>
> **WARNING**: `GITHUB_TOKEN` will be logged in shell history if not inserted through secure input or (depending on your shell config) the
> command is prefixed with a whitespace.

You're missing this `-s` parameter to provide valid token locally. Alternatively, if you have e.g. a `.env` file, you can use `--secret-file`, again per [the docs](https://github.com/nektos/act#secrets):

> #### Secrets
>
> To run `act` with secrets, you can enter them interactively, supply
> them as environment variables or load them from a file. The following
> options are available for providing secrets:
>
> - `act -s MY_SECRET=somevalue` - use `somevalue` as the value for `MY_SECRET`.
> - `act -s MY_SECRET` - check for an environment variable named `MY_SECRET` and use it if it exists. If the environment variable is
>   not defined, prompt the user for a value.
> - `act --secret-file my.secrets` - load secrets values from `my.secrets` file.
>
>   - secrets file format is the same as `.env` format